# Inconsistent columns and merge operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with a columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Tip
(
    ID int CONSTRAINT PK_Tip_ID PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Status varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Created date DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    Expiration date,
    Published date NOT NULL,
    Link varchar(255),
    Category varchar(50) CONSTRAINT FK_Category FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TipCategory(Name),
    Photo int CONSTRAINT FK_Photo FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TipPhoto(ID),
    Highlighted bit CONSTRAINT DF_Highlighted DEFAULT 0
);
```

I want to create procedure and use MERGE operation to do INSERT and UPDATE operations on a table in a single statement but I have one problem.
What if all columns (except ID of course) are inconsistent? 
I mean what if I want to change all single column from front end side and sending them to this procedure?
If I don't have at least one consist column so how can I find match like below:

```
MERGE Production.UnitMeasure AS target  
USING (SELECT @UnitMeasureCode, @Name) AS source (UnitMeasureCode, Name)  
ON (target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Name = source.Name  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (UnitMeasureCode, Name)  
    VALUES (source.UnitMeasureCode, source.Name)
```

I don't have any constant column to decide if this values should be insterted or updated.

Comment: 1. Why have you posted `Tip` table? 2. You are finding records by checking this condition `target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode` and if they are not matched, then you will insert a record, otherwise a record will be updated.

Comment: This is why identity columns shouldn't be used for a substitute for identifying keys in your actual data columns. You need to decide what *identifies* a row beyond "an arbitrary ID column". If *you* decide it's the `Title`, bang, there you go, that's how you distinguish an insert from an update.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever "This is why identity columns shouldn't be used for a substitute for identifying keys in your actual data columns." - could you explain with more details? To sum up I have to decide which column will identifies my row in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do insert or update depends on ID like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createEditTip
@ID int = NULL,
@Title varchar(100),
@Description varchar(255),
@Status varchar(10),
@Expiration date = NULL,
@Published date,
@Link varchar(255),
@Category varchar(50),
@PhotoID int,
@Highlighted bit

AS
BEGIN

    MERGE Tip AS target  
    USING (SELECT @ID, @Title, @Description, @Status, @Expiration, @Published, @Link, @Category, @PhotoID, @Highlighted) 
    AS source (ID, Title, Description, Status, Expiration, Published, Link, Category, PhotoID, Highlighted)  
    ON (target.ID = source.ID)  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET Title = source.Title,
                   Description = source.Description,
                   Status = source.Status,
                   Expiration = source.Expiration,
                   Published = source.Published,
                   Link = source.Link,
                   Category = source.Category,
                   Photo = source.PhotoID,
                   Highlighted = source.Highlighted
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
        INSERT (Title, Description, Status, Expiration, Published, Link, Category, Photo, Highlighted)  
        VALUES (source.Title, source.Description, source.Status, source.Expiration, source.Published, source.Link, source.Category, source.PhotoID, source.Highlighted);

    IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from TipCategory where Name = @Category)
    BEGIN
        insert into TipCategory
        values (@Category);
    END
END
```

I think it's quiet good solution.

Comment: And yet your original script updated a table named Production.UnitMeasure. Do you see why your question was very confusing now? Nor will this work if the value for Category in the update portion of your merge statement does not exist in this new TipCategory table.

Comment: Production.UnitMeasure was just example from MS documentation. Why it won't work? I have to pass Category to procedure. If Category doesn't exist in TipCategory it's not a problem because I will update row only in Tip and after that I will insert new Category into TipCategory. I have TipCategory table because I want to use this table in different features.